# how to trigger animation when the user scrolls to page section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using a simple animate.css animation on a div on my website. 
It all works fine however I want to trigger the animation when the user scrolls to that particular section on the site, rather than what it does currently which is running as soon as the website loads.

https://jsfiddle.net/u4ff2tfk/6/

This is the code so far:

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
@keyframes bounce {
  from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div data-anchor="intro-section-1" class="section intro-section-1">
  <div class="float-left ">
    <div id="executive-nav">
      <p onclick="openSideNavBlue()" class="nav-section-title">Executive Summary</p>
    </div>
    <div class="intro-text animated bounce">
      <p>It’s our sixth annual report and as the years go by, each iteration becomes an increasingly useful snapshot that captures the IT landscape both as it was over the last 12 months, and in transition from the years before it.
        <br>
        <br>There are 48 fewer respondents in this year’s survey than in 2015, although the number of respondents vary between large, medium and small organisations has stayed relatively consistent.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="float-right">
    <p class="intro-title">Welcome to
      <br>the 2016
      <br>Databarracks
      <br>Data Health
      <br>Check</p>
    <a href="#intro-section-2">
      <img class="blue-arrow" src="img/blue-arrow.svg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ozww5cvj/18/

The basic idea is to create a container. Within that container give some specifications of where exactly you want the animation to be I.E

```
var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
var imageHeight = $(this).height();
var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
```

You want to loop through this and then have an `if` statement checking the boundary conditions. If it  is indeed within the boundary, you can add a `class` which will have the necessary info for the transformation. I added the working fiddle on top.

Comment: I tried this out, but the element just seems to stay hidden and doesn't become visible or trigger the animation

Comment: Are you referring to your example, or my fiddle?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle of your code by the way, It will be easier to debug that way, I'll try and help you out.

Comment: I used the method you showed in your fiddle - which works, and placed it into my work where it doesn't

Comment: Ok, if you can add a fiddle ill try and help out :)

Comment: thanks! hopefully this might make it a bit clearer https://jsfiddle.net/u4ff2tfk/5/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not the best at css, but maybe you could try using jQuery to do the animation? It could then be basically whatever animation you'd prefer like maybe slideIn, fadeIn etc, and you could easily define it with an if statement.