# scale content scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to make a header with text (my logo) and this text while you make scroll down be scale, all of this be gradual until a specific part of the body  height.

like this : https://gph.is/g/ZObxbja
if does anyone know how make it please that write something.

This is the code in CSS.

```
#header {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#logo-nav {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 22px 0;
    height: 35px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    pointer-events: all;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "nimbu";
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#logo {
    margin-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: like this https://gph.is/g/ZObxbja

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this working example with JQuery : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39216430/7517148

However, if you don't want to use JQuery which is quite an heavy library, you could use some tool like [aos](https://css-tricks.com/aos-css-driven-scroll-animation-library/)

You did not specify which framework you could have been using in your project so I gave you some solutions that don't require a specific frameworks, but there are plenty of tools out there for animations like that.